# How can I add a variable number of months to a date using Workflow Designer in CRM2011?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011, designer

I'd like to do this in the graphical workflow designer witin CRM if possible, rather than resort to XAML or a custom assembly.

I want to set a date in a new record to the value of the corresponding date in another record, incremented by a number of months found in a third (related) record.  The application is bumping the renewal date of a membership by the duration of the membership type, which might be 3, 12, 24 or 60 months.

Any help appreciated, including telling me that it can't be done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done but you need to write a custom workflow activity, this because you need to fetch the related entities to retrieve the value.

[MSDN - Create a Custom Workflow Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx)

Comment: All of the related entities I need are available in the workflow designer, and I can see the fields that I need: StartDate in the old record and Duration in the product record.  I want to set StartDate in the new record to StartDate from the old record + Duration (which is an integer number of months) from the product record.

Comment: you still need a custom workflow activity, you can't add months to a date using standard functionalities

Comment: For info: Guido is correct that it cannot be done in the graphical workflow designer.  I worked around it by adding an IF condition for each Duration (8 possible values) and adding the appropriate constant for each condition.